# Slavic mythology, human-animal hybrid creature

Tags: mythical-creatures, slavic

In Greek mythologies, there are a lot of human-animal hybrid creatures (Satyr, Centaur or Lamia, to name a few...),  but I can't find any from Slavic mythos.

The best list I found is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Slavic_legendary_creatures) - but AFAIK there are only full-monster (like [Plivník](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cikavac), [Kikimora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikimora) or [Striga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strzyga)), or full-human (like [Mavka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mavka), [Rusalka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusalka) or vampire).

Is there any Slavic mythical human-animal hybrid creature? Or aren't there simply any?

Comment: Not sure these counts as hybrids, but I think the water spirit vodyanoy is kind of half man, half frog, and the swamp monster bolotnik is half man, half.. frog/ape/bug? They're certainly not tidy hybrids like centaurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hejkal, Čatež, Jezinka.

One is a black man completely coved in moss, lichen, grass and bracken. Very often with animal like claws and other features, such as small horns, or patches of fur or a tail. Germans probably took this myth and created Schrat. In more modern depictions, influenced by western culture it is a big fur ball with thin hands and legs. And its name is oftentimes intechangable with Divý muž (wild man), which I believe german folklore also took over (or the other way around, who knows...)

Čatež is a slavic equivalent of the Greek satyr. Sometimes with goat legs, sometimes with deer legs, sometimes with sheep or moufflon legs. Sometimes he filled the role of Lešij, played a flute and watched fairies dance. But most often he is depicted as a spirit helping woodcutters and other people who were living from the gifts of the forest. He refused to help or harmed those who have insulted him for his looks.

Jezinka is sometimes just a naked cannibalistic lady running around the woods, living in caves (that's where their names comes from). But sometimes they are depicted as half boar, from the waist down.